# Why sorting works in MySQL but not in the Coldfusion resultset?

Tags: mysql, sorting, coldfusion

I'm running `Coldfusion8/MySQL 5.0.88` and have a search whose results I need to sort `ASC/DESC` depending on user settings.

If I run this query inside MySQL, it works:

```
  SELECT a.*
  FROM artikelstammdaten a
        WHERE a.aktiv = "ja"
        AND a.firma LIKE '%test_comp%' 
  GROUP BY a.iln, a.artikelnummer, a.preis_aktuell, a.artikelbezeichnung
  HAVING sum(a.bestand) != 0 OR (a.nos = "ja" AND a.nos_anzeige = "ja")

  ORDER BY a.preis_aktuell ASC
  LIMIT 0, 24
```

This produces the expected result running in MySQL. But if I do this in Coldfusion:

```
 <cfquery datasource="db" name="results">
      SELECT a.*
           FROM artikelstammdaten a
           WHERE a.aktiv = "ja"
<cfif LOCAL.search.s_firma neq "" AND LOCAL.search.s_firma neq "Default">
           AND a.firma LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#LOCAL.search.s_firma#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    </cfif>
      GROUP BY a.iln, a.artikelnummer, a.preis_aktuell, a.artikelbezeichnung
      HAVING sum(a.bestand) != 0 OR (a.nos = "ja" AND a.nos_anzeige = "ja")

      ORDER BY <cfqueryparam value="#variables.sortierung#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> <cfqueryparam value="#variables.sortierung2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="4">
      LIMIT <cfqueryparam value="#variables.first#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">, <cfqueryparam value="#variables.last#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">
 </cfquery>
```

It just lists results without any order..

**Question:**
Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to get the sorting straight?

Thanks!

**Solution**:

```
<cfset variables.allowSort = "DESC,ASC,all_columns_names_that_are_ok,seperated_by_comma">
<cfif listfindnocase(variables.allowSort, variables.sortierung, ",") EQ 0>
    ORDER BY a.artikelnummer DESC
<cfelse>
    ORDER BY #variables.sortierung# #variables.sortierung2#
</cfif>
```

So in case the submitted values for either sorting column or sorting direction do not match the allow list, I'm using default sorting criteria, otherwise the submitted values.

Comment: Do not use `<cfqueryparam...>` in `ORDER BY`: http://www.chapter31.com/2008/11/22/cfqueryparam-does-not-work-in-order-by-what-are-my-options/

Comment: Cool! Do you want to make this an answer, so I can check?

Comment: Be sure to check both variables.

Comment: That's why I added DESC,ASC to the allow list.

Comment: @frequent - Yep, but the code only checks the first variable against the list. It needs to check both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `<cfqueryparam ...>` in `ORDER BY`.

[More information](http://www.chapter31.com/2008/11/22/cfqueryparam-does-not-work-in-order-by-what-are-my-options/) on this topic can be found in this blog post by Michael Sharman.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. I'm using an allow list. Editing my question.